# How can i remove .php extension from url

Tags: .htaccess

i have a website that have TWO LANGUAGE. so basically it was set up in .htaccess file. i want to remove the php extension

i've tried this code and still not working

this is the original code that i have

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
#RewriteRule en en/
#RewriteRule id id/
RewriteRule id/(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule en/(.*)$ $1
```

and this is the code that i've tried

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
#RewriteRule en en/
#RewriteRule id id/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ id/(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and the output says "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.